# Mapping an arbitrary spin graph to one with nearest neighbour interactions

Tags: simulations, spin-models, optimization

I remember having heard once that generic spin-graphs e.g. Ising, or at least 2-local ones (defined as the Hamiltonian contains pairwise interactions at most), can always be mapped to one another one (which will typically be larger), where every spin has at most neighbours. I'm not completely sure about the value of $n$, but seem to remember $n=3$
works. The physical motivation of working with spin graph with a maximum amount of neighbours is that it is possible to really build this in physical 2D or 3D space while keeping the notion of "nearest neighbour" interaction.

This also implies that finding ground states of 2-local Hamiltonians with max n
neighbours is an NP-hard problem.

Could someone confirm this and point me to a reference?

*note: an earlier version of this question has appeared on quantumcomputing.SE as https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/32454/.*

Comment: Someone answered, but the answer got removed?

Comment: it seems the answer got deleted because it was copied from a chatbot.

Comment: I am not sure about spin systems, but there are the so-called "chain mappings" for open quantum system Hamiltonians. I guess the principle is similar though. This probably just boils down to Lanczos algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) for the spin interaction matrix. I might be missing something though...

Answer (score 0):

The complexity class you want is QMA, which is the quantum counterpart of NP. Kitaev proved k-local Hamiltonians, k>2, are QMA-complete. Then the chain of reductions may be: k-local reduces to 2-local [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406180)], 2-local reduces to 2-local on a square lattice [[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504050)], 2-local on a square lattice reduces to 2-local on a hexagonal lattice [[3, figure 4.5, lemma 4.11]](https://research-information.bris.ac.uk/en/studentTheses/complexity-and-simulation-of-many-body-quantum-systems). Please check the papers to be sure that's what they say. Also be aware that there's all kinds of fine print associated with such reductions, e.g. see comments on Theorem 1 in [[4](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2686)]. But hopefully this much can get you into the literature, if you need true details.